# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Visual SourceSafe 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have installed in my Desktop Computer Visua Studio 2008 Team System 2008 Architecture and Visual SourceSafe 2005.

Visual Studio doesn't have integrated Visual SourceSafe, How can I integrate Visual SourceSafe on Visual Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug-in Selection.  Select Microsoft Visual SourceSafe

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008, go to

Tools -> Options -> Source Control

and select the Visual Sourcesafe plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the update on [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943847). Then SourceSafe should be available as a plugin (it sometimes isn't depending on what version of SourceSafe you installed).